# Migrating LDAP user and password to SAMBA4 AD

Tags: active-directory, openldap, samba4

As title suggests. We are migrating from OpenLDAP as user authentication to Samba 4 AD Domain. But I can't find any information on how to transfer passwords and users to Samba 4 AD. 
How to migrate all LDAP user base at ou=People,dc=company,dc=com to samba 4 AD domain?

I don't need to assistance transferring everything, I only need to transfer user accounts. I've finished migrating them all but user/passwords. Can it be done? If so, how?

Comment: 1. Search.. I have searched everywhere, and I know that Samba4 password is not compatible, but I need to transfer those passwords. There simply nothing exists on the web on how to transfer OpenLDAP to Samba4 AD. What have I tried? EVERYTHING. I transferred everything into Samba4 AD, but samba rejected any passwords. 2. What I tried to do described clearly there. I want to migrate all user and password. That's all. As for other entries, I've done myself. You don't need to care about that. 3. Details? openLDAP, and Samba4 AD as mentioned, Only 2 directory server, both are well known.
What else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The schemas for each are different, so there's no direct way to copy the LDAP data. You could write a script to translate data from one format to the other, I don't know of any tool that does this automatically.

Comment: ok.. I can write script, but I can't read the password for each user. How to transfer their passwords?

Comment: The password is probably in a different format anyway, so you probably can't do that.

Comment: Thank you.. so, I think the best way for me is to recreate users with random password. Is that correct?

Comment: It depends on your situation. If you use some kind of federated identity service you might be able to setup Samba beside LDAP for a time, when users change their passwords it gets updated in both locations. Once the passwords are synchronized you can cut over. If you don't have anything like that, you may be suck using random temporary passwords.

Comment: Okay.. I'll do that.. Both are running right now, but services still authenticated to ldap, since new Samba AD rejects every passwords. I already have PHP apps on my ldap server for user to manage their own OpenLDAP account, I think I can easily add routines there to update AD password as well. Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using JohnTheRipper on the password store,  then you'd probably have the real passwords to feed into the user creation script.