# How to synchronize OpenLDAP and Samba4?

Tags: openldap, samba4, sssd

I have a samba 4 domain with internal LDAP. Now the need arose to copy OpenLDAP users and passwords to this domain. This copy must be made synchronously every time there is a change in OpenLDAP. Reading some links, I understood that copying the password is difficult due to incompatibilities.

Looking on the internet I saw that there is a service called SSSD. Can it be used by Samba 4 to read OpenLDAP users effectively? If not, is there another alternative? Can you point me to materials?

**Links:**

[Migrating LDAP user and password to SAMBA4 AD](https://serverfault.com/questions/604299/migrating-ldap-user-and-password-to-samba4-ad)

Comment: Both OpenLDAP and samba LDAP support same protocol. You can make a script accessing both and do the job. This may work if you have both userPassword and sambaNTPassword in your OpenLDAP directory.

Comment: @kab00m So I don't know how to do this translation between types of passwords.

Comment: It depends, but in common case you don't have to. Both directories have them stored in same way.

Comment: @kab00m There seems to be a mismatch between password encryptions. So I can't import password from OpenLDAP to Samba4.

Comment: You need to be more specific about whole task and problems you experience.